# Xubuntu Keyboard partially responding after lid down only in some applications

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard, lock-screen

**Question: why this happens, how to track it down, how to fix?**

- Lid down > Lid up > Keyboard works.
- Lid down > Lid up > Keyboard in Firefox or Terminal doesn't work,
  Alt+Tab doesn't work > move (mouse) to Chrome or Mousepad, press any
  key, works > move back to Terminal or Firefox, works as well.

What happens? `dmesg` sees nothing that I can trace to keyboard.

Xfce 4, Xubuntu 14. Lid down should be "lock screen" (if my power manager can be trusted). I can work and mouse works, so if this happens I just mouse over, press a key and all is well but:

1. I'd like to know what happens and I prefer to have only one scenario (instead of sometimes having non-working keyboard in some apps)
2. Some day mouse may get that too and I'll be in trouble :)

Additional info:
Occasionally, I'd get a blank screen and this message (not verbatim, but close):

```
xscreensaver: couldn't grab keyboard. Already grabbed.
```

[https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=354559](Debian bug) I traced thanks to that is supposedly fixed, so I'll update my screen saver or disable it to see if it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was looking for a solution to the same issue as you, but the only effective solution I found on MX-15, XFCE 4.12 with Debian 8.2 was to disable xscreensaver altogether and rely upon the XFCE Power Manager to blank the screen after however many minutes you want. Disappointing if you want decent graphics or effects for your computer screen. At least it saves power on my Dell Latitude D630 (and no, I'm not proud of the fact I'm using a Dell product).

Explicit Directions:

> 1. Open XScreenSaver
> 2. Look for the drop-down menu labeled "Mode:".
> 3. Select "Disable Screen Saver".
> 4. Open the XFCE Power Manager.
> 5. Click on the "Display" tab.
> 6. Change the sliders listed in the row with "Blank after" listed at the start.
> 7. Enjoy the lack of issues.

I hoped this helps for some people, but this workaround is undesirable for people wanting a graphical screensaver.

Comment: And I admit that is precisely the only answer I arrived at as well. Therefore - have an accept and thank you!